# Include PDFs and make a table of content

Tags: table-of-contents, pdfpages

I am creating a PDF document composed of several other PDFs. I use latex to include those PDFs into a single pdf. I want to make a table of content of added PDFs. So, what I used for this is something like:

```
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage    
    \section{A}
    \includepdf[pages=1-2]{name_document1.pdf}
    \section{B}
    \includepdf[pages=1-2]{name_document2.pdf}
```

The table of content, in this case, would be:

```
Contents
1 A     2
2 B     5
```

the inconvenience of this method is that latex creates one blank page with only the section name. Meaning that on page 2, I have only the mention of 1 A and after two pages of name_document1.pdf, on page 5, the mention of 2 B and after the 2 pages of name_document2.pdf.

I can understand that this is simply the output of my code. But what I want to do, is to have a table of content with the proper names(titles) for each included pdf without creating a page only with that name/title. Something like that:

```
Contents
1 A     2
2 B     4
```

where on page 2 we have directly the name_document1.pdf and on page 4 the name_document2.pdf.

I know a very basic and non-automatic roundabout is to have two tex files. First, tableContent.tex:

```
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{A}
\newpage
\section{B}
\newpage
```

And include the PDF of this tex file into the second one as:

```
\includepdf[pages=1]{tableContent.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=1]{name_document1.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=1]{name_document2.pdf}
```

But this is only a detour and non-practical way if we include 100 pdfs. Is there a way to do what I have in mind?

Comment: Perhaps the pdfoverlay package would suit you. You could add lines to your table of contents easily at the appropriate places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method could be a little complicate. You need specify the `pagecommand` for each `\includepdf`. Following example show only include single page of PDF. It should worked for multi-page PDF as well. The contents line only be added at the first page. Also you need set the `insertpages` counter to 0 after your `\includepdf` command each time.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\newcounter{insertpages}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\includepdf[
pages=-,
pagecommand={
\thispagestyle{empty}
\stepcounter{insertpages}
\ifnum\value{insertpages}=1\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{example-image-a.pdf}\fi
}
]{example-image-a.pdf}\setcounter{insertpages}{0}

\includepdf[
pages=-,
pagecommand={
\thispagestyle{empty}
\stepcounter{insertpages}
\ifnum\value{insertpages}=1\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{example-image-b.pdf}\fi
}
]{example-image-b.pdf}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you Tom. Your response perfectly answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy with a TOC (i.e. you don't need a section heading on the inserted page) then you should try option `addtotoc` like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\includepdf[
  pages=-,
  addtotoc={
    1, section, 1, My first page, sec:FirstPage,
    5, section, 1, Page 5, sec:Page5}
]{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}

See page \pageref{sec:FirstPage} and \pageref{sec:Page5}.
\end{document}
```